# RunAndroid: startServerInNewWindow() issue in fresh React Nativeproject

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Fresh created project with react-native init.

If running "npm run start PORT=8081" or  "react-native start" and thereafter  "run-android"  in another node.js command prompt window, it works fine.

When running  "react-native run-android", it should open Node.js server in new window, but gives following error.

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/43995458/46674884-e049de00-cbfa-11e8-92cd-cd480056f964.PNG

Something needs to be fixed, maybe PATH environment variable.

P.S. New User, not enough reputation points, so had to put the image as link.

Environment Info -

D:\Users\Utkarsh Gupta\TestPro2>react-native info

React Native Environment Info:
    System:
      OS: Windows 7
      CPU: x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz
      Memory: 1.59 GB / 3.88 GB
    Binaries:
      Yarn: 1.10.1 - D:\Users\Utkarsh Gupta\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn.CMD
      npm: 6.4.1 - D:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD

Comment: //package.json

{
  "name": "TestPro2",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "^0.57.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.48.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.5.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}